# Webpack - bundle into single file or multiple files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

I have a website with a few types of page, each type requiring its own different set of js dependencies.

Should I be generating `bundle-welcome.js`, `bundle-shop.js`, `bundle-chatroom.js` etc and emit them to some directory which the backend can access? So basically one bundle per page type.

Or is best practice to use dynamically-generated template variables to extract the desired behaviour from a single, monolithic `bundle.js`, i.e. have a single, shared js resource sourced by every page on the domain?

Comment: there is some concept called code-splitting

Comment: Well, using multiple files would improve performance because you won't be loading things you don't need on a certain page. On the other hand, having one big bundle is simpler because you have only one file instead of many. So you have this trade-off and you need to decide what is better for you.